# Add Description to Route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am using Laravel 8.83.17.

Is there a way to add an additional information to a route? Something like this:

```
Route::get('/home', 'IndexController@index')->name('home')->description('Test');
```

Comment: What do you want to use this description for?

Comment: I am creating a screen where the user control permissions for each route, so I show the list of all routes and then a description.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such option on the Framework level.
In case if you need to have some documentation for your routes, ill recommend you to look at the - https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger

The package doesnt solve your problem, at least it provide you with a better overview of the routes.